# SensorSimulator Openintents simulating for 2 emulators

Tags: android, sensors

Hey is it possible to have two instances of Sensor Simulator connecting to a app running on 2 Emulators so that i can uniquely give motion events to each of the Emulator ?

Comment: you want to run your app on two simulators simultaneously or what?

Comment: ya ..i want to run my app on two android emulators..Each of them shld have a sensor simulator of its own..

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can run your android application simultaneously on two simulators. each simulator have there own id number just have look on left corner of your simulator you will get it.5554 and if you open another simulator again you will find number different like 5556 and all.

Comment: i guess u didnt get my question...My pblm is not with Android emulators..Its with openintents sensor simulator

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the socket in the preferences of the SensorSimulator (PC) and in the SensorSimulator Settings (Android App) in order to difference between the two app of the two emulator. You have to work with different sockets.